# Firefox issue with SSL on our IIS web server. Doesn't affect other browsers

Tags: firefox, iis, https, coldfusion, ssl-certificate

We have a Windows IIS 10 web server with a SSL certificate installed. We've noticed in the past, but more frequent recently, that various secured pages on our website are throwing off errors which don't make much sense. Sometimes it seems to lose session information. Other times it almost seems like it's loading a page twice perhaps, which is causing unique constraint errors on a page that is inserting something into the database.  When we go to try in IE/Edge or Chrome everything works great.  When I turn off SSL to test in Firefox, then Firefox works great as well.  I don't think there is an issue with the code per say because of this.  It's hard to pinpoint, but it seems like Firefox itself has some kind of issue with our current certificate setup.

I found this SSL checker (https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.research.buffalo.edu) and it lists everything as valid, and that the correct intermediate certificates are installed.

I'm not sure where else to go from here, but it's affecting our users fairly frequently now. Has anyone else run into these types of issues in Firefox only? Thanks.

I'm attaching a HTTP log from firefox as I get the error. I'm going from page A to page B (which should do an insert) and then redirect back to page A automatically.  In the IIS logs page B shows up twice with a 302 and then a 500 status code.  If I turn off SSL I see a 302 in the logs only and then it redirects back to page A.

https://pastebin.com/Yb4mNiKg

```
http log from firefox
```

I started sending emails on page B (the delete page that should redirect back to 
page A) to confirm that it does load the page twice.  The thing that caught my eye is on the first load it sends HTTP_CONNECTION: close in the cgi scope.  On the second load it sends HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive.  The rest of the information is basically the same.

Comment: Please add the error details you are getting ,without that nothing much can be done.No browser does load a twice no matter what errors come in SSL or network.Your client side code or ajax calls can trigger this issue.Or if the site loads slow,sometimes users themselves click on submit multiple times or refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks. The thing I'm noticing is that this usually happens on pages where I'm doing a redirect. So I'll start at page A and post to page B that does an 
 insert/delete usually and then immediately redirects back to page A. In the IIS logs page B will show up twice, first with a 302 status and then with a 500 status.  Same exact URL.  So it seems to be loading the page twice, which would be the reason I'm thinking why I see unique constraint errors.  It's trying to save the same information twice.

There is no ajax/javascript going on for these pages during the submit.

Comment: I added some more information up top again. It appears in Firefox only it loads the page twice and the first load it sends "HTTP_CONNECTION: close" in the headers for some reason.